# Scriptaculous vs JQuery for rich client side effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side, scriptaculous

Scriptaculous vs JQuery for rich client side effects.

What would you use and why?

Comment: That would depend on whether application is built with Prototype or jQuery. If it's Prototype, than Scriptaculous makes more sense. If neither, than jQeury would definitely result in a smaller foot print, comparing to Prototype + Scriptaculous bundle.

Comment: Adding to what @kangax said... jQuery is also included in the latest version of Visual Studio meaning it's got a long future ahead of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a search in stackoverflow: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913/what-javascript-library-would-you-choose-for-a-new-project-and-why), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221710/are-there-any-good-javascript-graphics-libraries), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040006/which-javascript-framework-is-better)

Or you could tell us why you've limited your options without explaining why. Are you writing an essay comparing the two or do you have something you want to accomplish?

If this is too much snark, then listen to kangax's comment.

Comment: Yeah where's Moo, YUI and Dojo?