# javascript graphics engine with zoom/mouse pan/rotate/text/events?

Tags: html, graphics, zooming, pan

Is there an open source javascript library able to create something like http://www.marcelbeumer.com/media/main/demos/ngen/index.html out of the box, or at most with a very simple plugin?

Note that you can:
 - zoom 
 - pan with the mouse
 - rotate
 - render text
 - click on items

Double points if it works in android/iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! Asked the author and it's on Github!

https://github.com/marcelbeumer/ngen-demo

Polymaps also looked like a contender - http://polymaps.org/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com). A javascript framework that works over SVG y VML. It's several functions and helpers, with scale (for zooming), pan, rotate, texting amongst them.

From the homepage:

> Raphaël is a small JavaScript library
> that should simplify your work with
> vector graphics on the web. If you
> want to create your own specific chart
> or image crop and rotate widget, for
> example, you can achieve it simply and
> easily with this library. Raphaël
> ['ræfeɪəl] uses the SVG W3C
> Recommendation and VML as a base for
> creating graphics. This means every
> graphical object you create is also a
> DOM object, so you can attach
> JavaScript event handlers or modify
> them later. Raphaël’s goal is to
> provide an adapter that will make
> drawing vector art compatible
> cross-browser and easy.

Example of usage:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");

// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
```

Hope it helps.

PS: Forgot to mention, the homepage has a LOT of examples, seeing is a must.

**EDIT:** A similar question was made some time ago here [Are there any good Javascript graphics libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221710/are-there-any-good-javascript-graphics-libraries)

Comment: Raphaël draws using SVG or VML, not canvas.

Comment: Ohh, you're right. It was a typo, thanks for the correction!!

Comment: Close but no cigar! To enable mouse zooming and panning you need a plugin (Raphael-ZPD), and no rotate. I'll update the question to make the requirements clearer.

Comment: Ah, that made things a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and I came across this Jquery javascript plugin 
http://arborjs.org/

it doesnt zoom and pan per se (it achieves it a bit differently) but since I saw this topic i was wth ill share it.